# Which SQL Implementation can translate to many other(s)?

Tags: sql, database

I'm looking for a SQL Implementation (and its Editor) that can be used for **translating** it to **many other(s) SQL Languages.**

For example, when i code in that SQL Language to script file(s), and then i translate to other(s) SQL Language script file(s) (for ex: MS SQL's , MySQL's , ...).

Comment: SQL is generally supposed to be universal. Yes there are differences but the core idea is the same and simple sqls generally are cross-db. Are you looking for translating some specific constructs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure to use only ANSI SQL to construct your scripts, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Justin Niessner: all SQL vendors pay attention to the SQL Standards, notably core SQL-92. To take SQL Server as an example, although they find Sybase legacy code is tricky to deprecate they are not afraid to do so and entirely new features (e.g. [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) in MSSQL2008) tend to extend their Standard SQL equivalents, rather than reinventing the wheel.

For a product that has good Standards compliance, take a look at [Mimer](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/index.htm)

> Here at Mimer Information Technology, we pride ourselves on conforming
>   to the SQL standard and we play an active role in the Database
>   Languages standardization group which determines exactly what is SQL
>   standard.

Mimer also provide extremely useful SQL validators for SQL-92, SQL-99 and SQL:2003 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I've been researching the same thing a while ago. What I've found is that there is a project [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). It is aimed at change tracking but also converting between different DBMS. You can download source code and see different datatypes conversions across databases. Source at [github](https://github.com/liquibase) browse for java files there, probably you'll find something helpful

Answer (score 1):

If all you want are basic operations, these are fairly universal.  For instance:

- `SELECT`
- `INSERT`
- `DELETE`
- `UPDATE`
- `FROM`
- `WHERE`
- `JOIN`

...are all at the most basic level the same across implementations.

However, the more complicated your scripts get, the more difficult it becomes to make them "universal".  Things like **aggregation, subqueries, cursors, while loops, functions, indexes, constraints, temp tables, variables, string manipulation, window operations** etc. are all pretty much database-specific.

Some of these do have "universal" equivalents but the more generic  you make your code the worse it will perform.